# Banno - Admin API - User Abilities

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When I call the User Abilities from the Banno API, it returns some users with their abilities listed and some users only return "{}". I believe this is because if a user has all of their user abilities set to the default value, the API doesn't return them. Can someone please confirm this?

If this is true, what is the default value of the zelle_enabled user ability? Is 'Request' the default value?

I have tried using 12 different test users and of the 12, 5 return {}.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Your post title should be a clear, specific question without tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the default for an institution will be based on the institution-configured abilities returned in `GET /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/abilities`.

However, there may be user-specific overrides which would be returned in `GET /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/abilities` (if they're *different* than the institution-configured ability).

- If a user does not have any user-specific overrides, then the `{}` empty response is returned (meaning that user is configured to use the institution-configured default).